# Test Function Against Every Table Value SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

`FINAL_VIEW`:

[image: FINAL_VIEW]

and `tblUnits`:

[image: tblUnits]

I need to check that every `Value` in `FINAL_VIEW`, if present in `Units` or if `LIKE` any field in `Correct_Unit`, is a case sensitive match for that `Correct_Unit`(presumably using `strComp(Value,Correct_Unit,0)`). I'm using this as a criteria for selection.

For instance, if `Value` was `BarG` it would be `LIKE barg` but would then evaluate to false on the `strComp()`.

The stage after this is to return the relevant `Correct_Unit` (in this case `barg`) in another field.

I have tried using a subquery within the `strComp()` but that doesn't work and I have no idea where ot go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't describe your tables. Just post the structure with sample data.

Comment: @dfundako is that better?

Comment: It's better, though the question is still confusing to understand.  Can you provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question can't have been particularly clear but I worked out a solution for both parts.

The key was to link `Value` with `Unit` and then perform the query, whilst having my `subStr()` in the `WHERE` clause and selecting the `Correct_Unit`.

Essentially, the linking did the work.

Here's my query for reference:

```
INSERT INTO tbluoms
SELECT final_view.controller      AS Controller,
       final_view.compound        AS Compound,
       final_view.contained_name  AS contained_name,
       final_view.strategytagname AS StrategyTagname,
       final_view.tagname         AS Tagname,
       final_view.block_cont_name AS Block_Cont_Name,
       final_view.name            AS Name,
       Cstr(final_view.value)     AS [Value],
       tblunits.[correct unit]    AS Correct_Value
FROM   tblunits
       INNER JOIN final_view
               ON tblunits.unit = Cstr(final_view.value)
WHERE  NOT (( [value] = [correct unit] ))
        OR Strcomp([value], [correct unit], 0)
           AND tagname NOT IN (SELECT [tagname]
                               FROM   [tbluoms])
           AND name LIKE "ei*"
           AND controller IS NOT NULL
           AND compound IS NOT NULL;
```